# Expression tree Convert() repeats twice

Tags: c#, linq, expression-trees

I'm trying to make LINQ to SQL, so I'm creating expression tree.

My problem is that `Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr` contains 'Convert()' twice instead only once. The result is `x => (Convert(Convert(x).Material) == 1)` instead of `x => (Convert(x).Material == 1)`

I created sample code to reproduce the problem. It has two objects - `House` and `Apartment`. They *implements* `IAddItem`. Interface `IAddItem` contains only one field, the *enumeration* `Material`. `Material` has two members `Bricks` and `Woods`.  `Building` class has one generic method `MaterialBuilding<T>`, which can receive `House` or`Apartment` or any other object that is implemented with `IAddItem`. And when the expression is created the result is `x => (Convert(Convert(x).Material) == 1)`

Why there are two converts instead of one, why is this happening? 
And is there any way to get around it?

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace Buildings
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            HouseObject ho = new HouseObject();
            ho.color = "red";
            ho.Material = Material.Woods;
            Building.MaterialBuilding(ho);
        }
    }

    public class Building
    {
        public static void MaterialBuilding<T>(T building) where T : IAddItem
        {
            Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr = null;
            expr = x => x.Material == Material.Woods;
            Console.WriteLine(expr);
           // Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public class HouseObject: IAddItem
    {
        public string color { get; set; }
        public int rooms { get; set; }
        public Material Material { get; set; }
    }
    public class ApartmentObject: IAddItem
    {
        public string color { get; set; }
        public int floors { get; set; }
        public int rooms { get; set; }
        public Material Material { get; set; }
    }
    public interface IAddItem
    {
        Material Material { get; set; }
    }

    public enum Material
    {
        Bricks,
        Woods
    }
}
```

The strange is that, when I start my [sample](https://repl.it/@stanimirsp5/Buildings) via online compiler, the result is with only one Convert(): `x => (Convert(x.Material, Int32) == 1)`

Comment: So the issue is not reproducible?

Comment: I think that if you run it local. You will be able to reproduce it

Comment: Add `class` constraint, e.g. `where T : class, IAddItem`

Comment: It works! Can you post it as an answer to approve it and can you explain why this works?